# Catch my message before push in Git

Tags: git, commit, githooks, commit-message

I am writing git hook client side `commit-msg` script and I need to put the message from

```
git commit -m "**mytext**"
```

into some script for further checking on my pattern.

I found how to do it with commits that were pushed

```
git log -1 --pretty=%B
```

But I did not find how to catch my message **before** push.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).
Read the section about the **Committing-Workflow Hooks**

> Committing-Workflow Hooks
>     The first four hooks have to do with the committing process.
>
> The prepare-commit-msg hook is run before the commit message editor is fired up but after the default message is created.
>   It lets you edit the default message before the commit author sees it.
>   This hook takes a few parameters: the path to the file that holds the commit message so far, the type of commit, and the commit SHA-1 if this is an amended commit.
>
> This hook generally isn’t useful for normal commits; rather, it’s good for commits where the default message is auto-generated, such as templated commit messages, merge commits, squashed commits, and amended commits. You may use it in conjunction with a commit template to programmatically insert information.